# Connecting to Amazon RDS instance through EC2 instance using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

In AWS I have a VPC set up with a Bastion Host. The bastion host is a single EC2 instance with a public address trough which you can SSH to any other server on the VPC.

I have created an RDS MySQL instance within the VPC and I would like to connect to it using MySQL workbench. I have followed the steps detailed [here](http://thoughtsandideas.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/monitoring-and-managing-amazon-rds-databases-using-mysql-workbench/), however in "Step 6: Setting up remote SSH Configuration", it asks me to "Provide the Public DNS of the Amazon EC2 instance" (i.e. the bastion host).

MySQL workbench then does checks for certain MySQL resources on that server. However, this is not correct in my opinion as I have provided the bastion host's address, which does not have MySQL installed. As a result, the last two checks for "Check location of start/stop commands" and "Check MySQL configuration file" then fail.

I have then tried using the endpoint address of the RDS MySQL instance but with no success (as it is in the private subnet so is not publicly addressable).

It seems that many people have this up and running, but what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've been struggling with something similar for weeks now. Just figured it out a few minutes ago.

1. In mysql workbench, create a new server instance.
2. For the remote host address, enter your endpoint address (i.e. xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com)
3. For connection method, select "Standard TCP/IP over SSH"
4. The SSH Hostname is the public DNS of your EC2 instance
5. I specified ec2-user (I believe it varies by EC2 Instance type) as the username and then specified the downloaded key file corresponding to the key pair the instance was using.
6. The mysql hostname is the endpoint of the RDS instance.
7. The username is the username for the RDS instance (i.e. ebroot)

Using that I was able to connect. However, I did not utilize VPC in my setup. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately (well fortunately actually) I no longer have to deal with this problem, and I don't want to spend money on RDS to check it. But if someone can tell me that this is working, I will accept the answer. Thanks for your response @AndrewSmiley.

Comment: You saved me day ! Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Since you are using a VPC,
this is how it should be configured in order to accept connections from your sub-net only:

1. select VPC Security Group used by your db instance
2. add a new rule to allow all ips from your private sub-net on port
   3306

   ex: Rule INBOUND  3306 (MYSQL)  172.33.11.0/24
3. use mysql workbench tcp/ssh and it will work (follow AndrewSmiley
   answer).

Comment: can you explain how to obtain this please? `ips from your private sub-net`

Comment: nm,  this is the private IP from the instance you created on `step 1` of Andrew's answer

Comment: Using my ec2 private subnet/32 did not work, but my ec2 private subnet/24 did. I didn't see this anywhere in the documentation, but I'm new at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using SSH tunneling:

1. Create putty session to the bastion host
2. Under Connection --> SSH --> Tunnels, specify the Source port: 3306, Destination: yourRDSendpointname:3306
3. Don't forget to click add!
4. Connect to the bastion host with those settings
5. Add a new connection in MySQL workbench and point it to your localhost port 3306 (assuming you aren't running anything on 3306 on your local client machine)
6. Put in your username and password for your RDS instance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truly use the VPC connectivity of AWS and not allow public IPs do the following.

If you have one security group that both your EC2 and RDS are assigned to then add an inbound rule for mysql 3306 on TCP but in the source field do not put IP or subnet but the actual security group ID. ie sg-9829f3d2.

I personally have two security groups on VPC.

The first, security group 1 is in use by the EC2 instance and only allows the ports required for the EC2, ie 80 and 22.

The second, security group 2 is in use by just the RDS instance(s) and has one rule for allowing mysql (3302) and the source field is set to the id of security group 1.

All the Mysql workbench SSH tunnelling works with the two security groups as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an SSH tunnel into your Bastion host (EC2 instance) to forward ports from your local machine to the remote RDS instance.

on mac/ linux this is the command (for windows follow instructions in the link below):

```
ssh -L 3306:myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306  your_c2_ip
```

then you can connect with workbench using the following settings:

- connection method: standard TCP
- hostname: localhost
- port 3306

This post explains it the method in more detail;
https://userify.com/blog/howto-connect-mysql-ec2-ssh-tunnel-rds/

Answer (score 1):

***This is for UBUNTU Mysql workbench***

You must add an inbound rule to the security group linked with the RDS to accept requests on port 3306 from the bastion/jump/any instance(**machine**).
The machine should have a public IP associated with it.

Do confirm on your **machine** if you can connect with the RDS or not first, before trying to setup the SSH tunnel through MYSQL workbench.

To test connectivity run:

```
mysql -u{username} -p{password} -h ***-db-***.cmmaberpdqoc.***.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306
```

Replace {username}, {password} and host with your credentials.

Follow the picture and you should be able to connect.

[image: Pictorial representation of the details to be entered.]

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the issue for me. On the RDS dashboard have a look at the security group for your instance. Click on this and it would take you to the security  group page.

Although it would say "All traffic" for both Inbound and Outbound click edit and ensure the source says My IP. I would not recommend using all IP's as this would open it to any one on the internet. If you do not have a static IP then ensure that you refresh this field once the connection stops working.

After this I was able to connect to the AWS RDS T2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

MAKE SURE YOU ARE USING A .PEM FILE WHEN CONNECTING TO AN EC2 INSTANCE. Assuming you have everything else setup correctly this could be the issue.

Uploading a public rsa key will allow you to ssh into the bastion host via the terminal. However, this key will not work when using MySql Workbench.