# MySQL Workbench AWS EC2 With Non publicly accessible RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

I have set up a new RDS instance within my VPC that is not publicly accessible.

I can connect via WorkBench and create new schemas and do other miscellaneous tasks, however, when I try to import (Data Import) whether from dump or self contained I get "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (61)"

I am connecting following Andrews advice:
[Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129428/connecting-to-amazon-rds-instance-through-ec2-instance-using-mysql-workbench)
Also, 
[Monitoring and Managing](https://thoughtsandideas.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/monitoring-and-managing-amazon-rds-databases-using-mysql-workbench/)

Any ideas why I can connect successfully and do some manipulations but cannot import?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you connecting to the RDS server directly from an EC2 instance within the subnet? I believe this is the only way the data import will work - if you're using a public instance in the VPC acting as a gateway or SSH tunnel and are trying to import data from your local (non-AWS) machine, it probably can't reconcile the import through the proxy.

Try putting the data you want to import locally in an EC2 in the subnet, and run it from there.

Comment: Monkey yep... after reading your reply that was the issue.  What i found is there was two ways to do it... do a dump from current db then import into EC2 like you said or launch a new non public instance from existing instance snapshot.  after its all set up... its ALL GOOD!